# Tastypie query limit

Tags: python, django, tastypie, throttling, django-piston

Is there any way to handle query per user limitations with tastypie API library ?

I would like for example to limit all users to 200 queries per day.

I looked all over the documentation and only found how to handle query results ranges limitations.

Edit : I found out that [piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation) was proposing query throttling but everywhere people say that tastypie is better than piston.

Comment: Perhaps you could utilize the global cache, a KEY/VALUE store, or a custom database model?  I don't believe Tastypie supports this functionality out of box, but it should be trivial for you to add it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alex, I also though of implementing compulsory [authentication](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html) and add a query count field in the DB for each user which would be incremented at each query.
I hoped there might be a more official / clean solution.